# csv writer using buffer results in empty output

Tags: go

I have created a function to get some data and write them to CSV and the output is stored on a buffer.

```
type OptIn struct {
    Email      string `json:"email"`
    LastUpdate string `json:"opt_in_last_update"`
}

func writeCSV(data []OptIn) ([]byte, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    writer := csv.NewWriter(&buf)

    defer writer.Flush()

    for _, obj := range data {
        var record []string
        record = append(record, obj.Email)
        record = append(record, obj.LastUpdate)
        err := writer.Write(record)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
    }

    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

The problem is that the `buf.Bytes()` is always empty, even though the input is not empty and there are no errors thrown.

Comment: You are calling Bytes() before Flush().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to call `writer.Flush()` before calling `.Bytes()` and check [`.Error()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Writer.Error) before returning:

```
  // TODO: remove `defer writer.Flush()`
  // ...

  writer.Flush()

  if err := writer.Error(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  return buf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

Your sample code does things in the following order:

1. call `buf.Bytes()`
2. return the generated byte slice and nil
3. call `writer.Flush()`

Clearly this is not the intended order since we need to flush (and check for any writer errors!) before accessing the generated byte slice.